# i just started coding from now , i want to know some basic codes to start with

Tags: json

How can i start my journey by writing codes using AI
Any help will be appreciated.

tried using AI Generated codes but didn't know how to use them. tried writing the same way on command board but it started showing error.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The same way you start anything... at the beginning.  For any given tool or technology that you want to use, your favorite search engine can help you find introductory tutorials and examples.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please read tour - https://stackoverflow.com/tour and how to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AI for code-generation is a great tool that can help you write better code. However, assuming you're not familiar with programming, you would benefit most by first learning the basics, such as learning a programming language and building your skillset with it, from which you'd then be able to make use of AI-assisted coding.

For myself, I first learned how to program computers beginning with BASIC (on a [Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64)!), then learning z80 assembler, and then learning C. Back in those days, I had to read manuals and other books and magazines. Today, there are a ton of resources available that can teach you programming.

One of the best, in my humble opinion, is Harvard University's [CS50x course](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/). It serves as a fantastic introduction to programming and will help you set a solid foundation for yourself in your journey as a programmer. However, if college-level coursework is beyond your current reach, there are many other resources that can help introduce these concepts at a more appropriate level. For instance, MIT has a program called [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu) that aims to teach programming to children between the ages of 8-16. There are additional resources at websites like [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com) and [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org).

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_. Questions that aren't on-topic (meaning, narrowly focused on a specific technical problem with enough details to allow answers to be tested to solve that problem) should be closed, not answered.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah, thank you for pointing that out. I glanced over that article but must have misunderstood it. I'll give it a good read.

Answer (score -1):

First start practicing code by yourself, that would help you. Open this URL, https://www.w3resource.com/index.php, It has good stuff of practice question. All the best!

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_. Questions that aren't on-topic (meaning, narrowly focused on a specific technical problem with enough details to allow answers to be tested to solve that problem) should be closed, not answered.